# FTP client fails on Windows Server 2003 R2 (64bit)

Tags: windows-server-2003

Dell server, running Windows 2003 R2 (64-bit). I cannot FTP from this server using ftp.exe.  I have other users sharing the Internet connection and they are having the same problem.  Basically it sends a packet and hangs, and the receiving end thinks the client closed the connection. This occurs with multiple FTP servers, so it's not specific to one server.

Can't even do a LS command, much less transfer a file. From one of the FTP servers' log:

```
06:53:03 Accepted connection from [ip address]
06:53:10 Command "USER xxxx" received
06:53:13 PASSword accepted
06:53:13 User xxxx logged in.
06:53:29 Command "PORT xx, xx, xx, xx,19,137" received
06:53:29 PORT set to xx.xx.xx.xx - 5001 (19,137)
06:53:29 Command "NLST" received
06:53:29 NLST started successfully for path/wildcard
06:53:30 Transfer terminated by client closing connection
06:53:30 Transfer aborted
```

If I do try to transfer a file it sends 2920 bytes and then fails with the same sort of `"client closed the connection"` error.  I initially assumed it was a firewall problem but I even (briefly!) turned off the firewall and got the same results. I use WinZip Pro to do a backup with FTP, and it fails in the same way.

The server is directly connected to the cable modem (dual homed machine) so there's no NAT externally getting in the way. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same thing with windows xp 64 bit, took a xp32 bit copy of ftp.exe and that worked without problem.